# I've jammed my shoulder -- I don't understand what exactly is meant by "jammed" here

Tags: meaning

From the movie [The Da Vinci Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Da_Vinci_Code_%28film%29) (2006)

Example:

> What happened between you and your grandfather, Sophie? I've **jammed my shoulder**, I've been shot at, I'm bleeding. I need to know. You say he raised you, but you two don't talk anymore.

What does it actually mean to jam one's shoulder?

Comment: [Definition 1a](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jam): *to become blocked or wedged*

Comment: I must admit the expression seems highly ambiguous to me too. Maybe because it is highly dependent on the previous context.

Comment: According to The Free Dictionary, it means to crush, bruise or smash.

Comment: Perhaps it is okay to think that it really means 'jammed', in the sense that it cannot be moved due to an injury - dislocated/fractured bone/s, the joints or the muscles 'malfunction' - jammed his knee, he can't walk properly; jammed his mandible, he can't chew quickly; jammed his elbow, he can't shoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injured it, by having it get hit or banged into, or his arm being rammed into the shoulder socket.